# How To Send email alert on log file entry with awk in Linux?

Tags: email, awk, system, monitoring

I'm working on a script to monitor a log of jobs executed and I want to receive a mail notification with the line where appears the job in the body of the mail. This is what I got so far but it keeps throwing error, I can make it work but just with an empty body. Could you please help?

```
Job="jobname"

tail -fn0 logfile.log | awk -v Jobs="$Job"'/jobname/ 
{ 
    system("grep -i "Jobs" logfile.log | mail -s "Jobs Is Completed" mail@mail.com") 
    exit
}'
```

Comment: Insert a space between `"` and `'`.

Comment: You'll need to escape some of the inner quotes in the `system` command string.

Comment: And remove the newline between `/jobname/` and the opening `{` of the action.

Comment: A shell is a tool to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to other tools. Awk is a tool to manipulate text. You're trying to use awk to sequence calls to the tools grep and mail - that's not what awk is for, that's what a shell is for, so don't do this. [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you do what you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just:

```
Job="jobname"
tail -fn0 logfile.log |
grep --line-buffered -i "jobname.*$Job" |
mail -s "$Job Is Completed" mail@mail.com"
```

Your use of `jobname` as literal in 2 places and a shell variable named `Job` with an awk variable named `Jobs` populated from it and both containing `jobname` anyway was very confusing so hopefully you can tweak the above to do whatever you need to do if the variable usage above is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

**watchdog.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
mailWorker(){  
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == *$match* ]]
        then
            # mailing
            grep -i "Jobs" "$logfile" | mail -s "Jobs Is Completed" mail@mail.com 
            break
        fi
    done
}

logfile="/path/to/logfile.log"
match="jobname" 

if [ ! -f "$logfile" ]; then
  touch "$logfile"
fi

tail -f --lines=0 "$logfile" | mailWorker
```